# Transform duration in seconds to DD HH:MM:SS format (Informix)

Tags: sql, informix

Column *duration* provides contact duration in seconds (integer 8) and it can be longer than day. I use this solution:

```
select ((INTERVAL(0 0:0:0) DAY TO SECOND) + callend UNITS SECOND) as dur from callrecord
```

This produce results like:

```
0 00:08:17
13 19:10:12
```

Idea is to omit days when there are 0 days:

```
   00:08:17
13 19:10:12
```

I didn't succeeded playing with TO_CHAR.
Some ideas announced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709500/transform-from-interval-10504-to-hhmm-format-informix-11-50), but I still can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert the value to a string.  My Informix syntax is a little weak, but something like this:

```
select (case when called < 24 * 60 * 60
             then to_char((interval(0 0:0:0) day to second) + callend units second), '%D %H:%M:%S')
             else to_char((interval(0:0:0) hour to second) + callend units second), '%H:%M:%S')
        end) as dur
from callrecord;
```

Comment: This outputs just integers:
      `63`
      `7200`
      `2027`

Comment: @Vodnik . . . `TO_CHAR()` is more explicit for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, TO_CHAR have many format options for INTEGER, DATE and DATETIME, but not for INTERVAL. Seems it can't output number of days. That's why others here use  TODAY::DATETIME DAY TO SECOND + callend UNITS SECOND. This can be converted with TO_CHAR, but there will be problem when duration is longer than day.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found this code produces the desirable result:

```
    select CASE 
      WHEN TRUNC(cr.callend/86400)=1 THEN TRUNC(cr.callend/86400)||' day '
      WHEN TRUNC(cr.callend/86400)>1 THEN TRUNC(cr.callend/86400)||' days '
      ELSE ''
    END||TRUNC(MOD(cr.callend,86400)/3600)||':'
       ||TRUNC(MOD(MOD(cr.callend,86400),3600)/60)
       ||':'||MOD(MOD(MOD(cr.callend,86400),3600),60) as dur
    from callrecord cr
```

Though looking not very elegant, this SQL runs even faster than one in initial example.